# Blackberry: problem with RichTextField

Tags: java, blackberry, richtext

I want to add some text to a screen. Since this text changes color according to the words I decided to use a `RichTextField`.
Here is my code:

```
String productName = product.getProductName()+": ";
String price = String.valueOf(product.getPrice());
Font[] fonts = new Font[2];
fonts[0] = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, 12);
fonts[1] = fonts[0].derive(Font.BOLD);
byte[] attribs = new byte[] {0, 1};
int[] offsets = new int[] {0, productName.length(), productName.length() + price.length()};
int[] fontColors = new int[] {Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN};
int[] backColors = new int[] {Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE};
RichTextField labelPrice = new RichTextField(productName + price, offsets, attribs, fonts, Field.FIELD_LEFT|FIELD_VCENTER);
labelPrice.setAttributes(fontColors, backColors);
```

I can add the text and there is no problem but the background. The first letter of my `product` has a blue background, im not adding any blue anywhere else, and even if i was, i would expect that it would be overriden with `backColors`. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT:** I'm just fixing the code here that raukodraug pointed out for rookies like me

```
RichTextField labelPrice = new RichTextField(productName + price, offsets, attribs, fonts, Field.FIELD_LEFT|FIELD_VCENTER|Field.NON_FOCUSABLE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think your problem is not that it has a blue background but that it is focused. Try to move the trackwheel and you will see.
You should add `Field.NON_FOCUSABLE` to the `RichTextField` styles. I'm pretty sure that will fix your problem.
As you can see [here](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/RichTextField.html) you should do this so it cannot accept focus.
I hope this helps

Comment: Oh well, that was rookie error, thanks a lot for your help raukodraug.

Comment: @chekemp np, i hope it helped :)